# How do we know if an integral converges or diverges from a limit?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

If we know that the limit of $f(x)$ approaches infinity equals some value like $5$, how can I show that $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\text{ }dx$$ converges or diverges?

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that it diverges. Here's how:

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=5$, then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x>\delta$, $|f(x)-5|<1$. This latter inequality is equivalent to $4<f(x)<6$, showing that $f(x)>4$ for all $x>\delta$.

It is clear that the integral $\int_{\delta}^{\infty}4\text{ }dx$ diverges, so $\int_{\delta}^{\infty}f(x)\text{ }dx$ diverges by the integral comparison test. Adding a finite integral like $\int_{0}^{\delta}f(x)\text{ }dx$ doesn't affect convergence/divergence, so $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\text{ }dx$ is also divergent.

Answer (score 0):

$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges if in $f(x)$ is finite and continuous (or piece-wise continuous) in $[0,\infty)$ and $|f(x)|$ vanishes faster that $|x|^{-1}$ as $x \to \infty$. For instance
$I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x} dx$ diverges, $I_2=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} dx$ conveges, $I_3=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x^4)^{1/4}}$ diverges because the integrand when $x \sim \infty$ behaves as $f(x)\sim  \frac{1}{|x|^\beta}, \beta=1$. For convergence, $\beta >1$.